# Converse, Inverse and Contrapositive of this theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, divisibility

> **Theorem**: If $a|m$ and $a|n$ then $a|mx+ny$, where $a,m,n,x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$.

I was studying this result from number theory recently. I was wondering whether the inverse and converse and contrapositive of this theorem is also true. I have seen some examples where it seemed to me that these theorems are being used but there was nothing mentioned except for the above theorem. I am not sure. I don't remember exactly but it was something along the lines of $p_i\nmid p_1p_2\cdots p_k+1$ where $i\in\{1,2\cdots, k\}$.

> **Inverse of the theorem**: If $a\nmid m$ and $a\nmid n$ then $a\nmid mx+ny$ , where $a,m,n,x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$.
>
> **Converse of the theorem**: If $a|mx+ny$ then $a|m$ and $a|n$, where $a,m,n,x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$.
>
> **Contrapositive of the theorem**: Let $a,m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$. If there exist $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a\nmid mx+ny$ then $a\nmid m$ and $a\nmid n$.

Is the inverse, converse and contrapositive of this theorem true?

Comment: I think you need to be a little bit careful with the quantifiers here: Let $a,m,n\in\mathbb N$. If $a\mid m$ and $a\mid n$, then $a\mid(mx+ny)$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb N$. This makes the contrapositive of the theorem: if there exist $x,y\in\mathbb N$ such that $a\nmid (mx+ny)$, then $a\nmid m$ or $a\nmid n$.

Comment: @Clayton, may I ask what is the difference between both and whether the statements for inverse and converse will also have to be changed?

Comment: To unify them you can use: $ $ if $\ a\mid m\ $ then $\ a\mid mx\!+\!ny \iff a\mid ny.\ $ Thus $\,p_j\mid p_1\cdots p_k\,$ hence $\,p_j\mid p_1\cdots p_k + 1\iff p_j\mid 1\ \ $

Comment: In the first statement, you're showing the statement holds for **all** pairs $x,y\in\mathbb N$. In the second statement, you're assuming that there exists at least one pair $x,y\in\mathbb N$ such that the statement does not hold.

Comment: Every statement is equivalent with its contrapositive. Furthermore, the inverse of a statement is the contrapositive of the converse of the statement, hence the inverse and the converse of a statement are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement, with variables restricted to Z, is
a|m and a|n implies a|mx + my.

The inverse is
not(a|m and a|n) implies not(a|mx + my)
which is equivalent to
(not-a|m or not-a|n) implies not(a|mx + my).

The contrapositive is
not(a|mx + my) implies not(a|m and a|n)
which is equivalent to
not(a|mx + my) implies (not-a|m or not-a|n).

Were the statement considered to be
a|m and a|n implies for all x,y, a|mx + my

then inverse is
not(a|m and a|n) implies not(for all x,y, a|mx + my)
which is equivalent to
(not-a|m or not-a|n) implies exists x,y with not-(a|mx + my),

The converse is
(for all x,y, a|mx + my) implies a|m and a|n,

and the contrapositive is
not(for all x,y, a|mx + my) implies not(a|m and a|n)
which is equivalent to
exists x,y with a|mx + my) implies (not-a|m or not-a|n).

Whether the inverse, converse or contrapositive holds can depend upon how you consider the qualifiers.  I think the text intends the first simple version.

In that case consider when x = y = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting "where" as "for all", the Inverse, Converse, and Contrapositive are false. To refute a generality it suffices to give a single counter-example.

Inverse: $a=2$ and $m=n=x=y=1.$

Converse: $a=2$ and $m=n=x=y=1.$

Contrapositive: $a=m=2$ and $n=x=y=1.$

Comment: The contrapositive of a true statement is always true. In particular, your third counterexample doesn't work.

Comment: I used "contrapositive" to refer to what the proposer wrote, which is not the correct use of the word. If $a=m=2$ and $n=1$ then there do exist $x,y$ such that $a|(mx+ny)$, e.g. $x=y=1$ because $2\not |(2\cdot 1+1\cdot 1)$ but it is not true that $(2\not |2)\land (2\not |1).$ It seems to me that the proposer may have mistakenly  taken $((\neg a|m)\land (\neg (a|n))$ as the logical negation of $(a|m\land a|n).$

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that the OP made a mistake in distributing the logical negation over the logical conjunction. I worry that your answer, instead of helping the OP make sense of things, will confuse him more instead.

Comment: @posilon. The proposer will automatically be notified of our exchange of comments.